# Python code to read metadata from raster file

Tags: python, raster, metadata

Can you provide me with Python code to read metadata from a raster file?

Answer (score 6):

Two options:

1. Use GDAL Python bindings.
2. Run GDALINFO from python and capture the stdout, to get a string with the metadata:

---

```
import os
metadata = os.popen('gdalinfo ../rasterfile.tiff').read()
print metadata
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use **gdalinfo**: http://www.gdal.org/gdalinfo.html

Answer (score 0):

```
from osgeo import gdal

filename=gdal.Open("file path")

metadata=filename.GetMetadata()

print(metadata)
```

Comment: Even if the answer is simple, coding answers should also contain words describing the solution (and, ideally, a documentation reference).  "Wall of code" answers are likely to receive a similar response to "Wall of code" questions (down-voting and removal). Please take the [Tour] to get a better idea of how GIS SE operates.